# Codeigniter 4 - composer update to v4.4 issues

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Just ran `composer update`, upgrading to CodeIgniter v4.4 Now Codeigniter does not work, the log shows the error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "CodeIgniter\ENVIRONMENT"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Upgrade to CodeIgniter 4.4**

The following files received significant changes and you must merge the updated versions with your application:

- public/index.php
- spark

If you have not changed index.php or spark, just copy the new versions of these files from the v4.4 framework. Otherwise, merge the new versions with your current files.

```
cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/public/index.php public/index.php
cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/spark spark
```

**After** fixing the above, you may still have to update some Config files. Check the following Config changes-:

```
Uncaught ErrorException: Undefined property: Config\App::$allowedHostnames in /home/dev/src/php/providr/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/HTTP/SiteURIFactory.php:246
```

**App/Config/App.php**

Check there is a `$allowedHostnames` property in the App class.  If you want to accept multiple Hostnames, set this property to your hostnames.

```
public array $allowedHostnames = [];
```

The property $proxyIPs must be an array. If you don’t use proxy servers, it must be

```
public array $proxyIPs = [];
```

**app/Config/Routing.php**
Routing.php is a new Config file which holds settings that used to be read from Routes.php.

- Copy app/Config/Routing.php from the new framework to your app/Config
  directory, and configure it. Remove all settings in
- app/Config/Routes.php that are no longer needed.
- If you use the environment-specific routes files, add them to the $routeFiles property in app/Config/Routing.php.

Hopefully CodeIgniter will now fire up. But also check the following files which have changes:
app/Config/Cookie.php
app/Config/Security.php
app/Config/Session.php

For full details of all v4.4 changes see [CI4 docs - upgrade to v4.4](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_440.html)